# ASP.NET CORE Render Razor View to string with controller parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to render a partial view as string.
For this I use following Helper class:

```
public static string RenderRazorViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model = null)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        IViewEngine viewEngine =
            controller.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as
                ICompositeViewEngine;
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, false);

        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
            controller.ControllerContext,
            viewResult.View,
            controller.ViewData,
            controller.TempData,
            sw,
            new HtmlHelperOptions()
        );
        viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

This works but I now need a similiar Method that also accepts a list of parameters.
The View I want to render as a string is called by following Controller method:

```
public Task<IActionResult> IndexPartial(string? searchValue, string? filterValue)
{
   IQueryable<Invoice> query
   ....Manipulate query by searchValue and filterValue
   return PartialView("IndexPartial",await query.ToListAsync());
}
```

When I call `Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(controller, "IndexPartial", model)` I have to pass the stringValue and FilterValue.

Does Anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Crztean,Did my answer help you resolve your issue?Or maybe you still have any doubt?

Comment: @Rena Hi no everything fine, I now understood the idea behind it and that I was thinking about it in a wrong way, which is great thank you. I marked your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may understand the usage of `RenderRazorViewToString`.This method is called by the following code:

```
Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(controller, "PartialViewName", model);
```

The second parameter is not the method name,it is the partial view name.It would not get to the `IndexPartial` method.

What you want is to parse the partial view with model to string.The model data get by manipulating query by `searchValue` and `filterValue`.

To meet your requirement,what you need do should be like below:

```
public string IndexPartial(string? searchValue, string? filterValue)
{
    var model = _context.Pupils
                    .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(searchValue)&& a.Email.Contains(filterValue))
                    .FirstOrDefault();  //Manipulate query by searchValue and filterValue
     
    //pass the correct model to the RenderRazorViewToString method
    //then it would render the partial view to the correct string
    var data = Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "PartialViewName", model);
    return data;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe you can use an expression instead of a string parameter, like the following:

conditionLambda: p => true, orderLambda: p => p.Naam

   public PagingViewModel<T> GetPaging(int page, int pagesize, Expression<Func<T, bool>> conditionLambda, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderLambda)
    {
        var items = _context.Set<T>()
                        .Where(conditionLambda)
                        .OrderBy(orderLambda)
                        .Skip(page * pagesize)
                        .Select(t => t)
                        .Take(pagesize)
                        .ToList();
```